# ¿Cómo pasar de decimal a binario en Haskell? ACTUALIZADO

Tags: haskell

Buenas tardes.

¿Hay alguna función que permita pasar de decimal a binario? Por ejemplo,

```
toBin 12 = [1,1,0,0]

toBin 2^38-174 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0]

toBin 1215484521248 = [1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

He intentado hacerlo mediante recursión, de la siguiente forma, pero es muy poco eficiente, pues en los ejemplos anteriores, ni me lo da en el mismo orden y tarda mucho.

```
toBin 0 = [0]

toBin n | mod n 2 == 1 = toBin (div n 2) ++ [1]

        | mod n 2 == 0 = toBin (div n 2) ++ [0]
```

Asimismo, después necesito que me diga el número de unos que hay en el número
Por ejemplo,

`numeroUnos [1,1,0,0] = 2`

Este último no se me ha ocurrido nada para hacerlo.

**ACTUALIZADO.2**

El problema es que me lo piden para este número 20^100000000+37,  y ambas definciones son ineficientes, tanto la mía como la de los comentario.

`numeroUnos (1+10^20000000) = a`

Necesito la función que me diga cuantos unos tiene ese numero en binario, **en menos, de 10 segundos.**

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: @ChemaCortes a ver si me puedes ayudar, porque eres un genio en Haskell. Además, creo que eres de los pocos aquí que lo entiendes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En [`Data.Bits`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Bits.html) existe una función, `popCount`, para contar el número de `1's` de un número en binario:

```
Prelude> import Data.Bits
Prelude> :set +s
Prelude Data.Bits> popCount (1+10^20000000)
23216588
(1.36 secs, 32,704,936 bytes)
Prelude Data.Bits> popCount (20^100000000+37)
116093520
(10.84 secs, 214,531,880 bytes)
```

Si lo tienes que hacer por tus propios medios, no conseguirás eficiencias mayores.

Sin usar `Data.Bits`, se me ocurre algo así:

```
numeroUnos :: Integer -> Int
numeroUnos 0 = 0
numeroUnos n | odd n     = numeroUnos (n `div` 2) + 1
             | otherwise = numeroUnos (n `div` 2)
```

En lugar de ir bit por bit, podemos ir por bloques de 8 bits:

```
numeroUnos2 :: Integer -> Int
numeroUnos2 0 = 0
numeroUnos2 n = b256!!(fromInteger r) + numeroUnos2 d
  where
    b256 = [numeroUnos n | n <- [0..255]]
    (d,r) = divMod n 256
```

Hay que notar que `numeroUnos2` usa la función anterior, `numeroUnos`, para calcular la lista `b256`.

Podemos escalar e ir en bloques de 16 bits:

```
numeroUnos3 :: Integer -> Int
numeroUnos3 0 = 0
numeroUnos3 n = b16!!(fromInteger r) + numeroUnos3 d
  where
    b16 = [numeroUnos n | n <- [0..2^16-1]]
    (d,r) = divMod n (2^16)
```

Pero no mejora mucho, incluso parece ir bastante peor.

Answer (score 1):

## Decimal a binario

El problema de tu implementación es que estás concatenando cada dígito al final de la lista en cada iteración. El operador `++` tiene un coste lineal respecto al número de elementos de la primera lista. Por lo tanto, si el número binario tiene `n` dígitos, hace `(n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + ... + (n-n) = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (n-1)` iteraciones para construir la lista final, cuya [progresión](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progresi%C3%B3n_aritm%C3%A9tica) es igual a `(n-1)*n/2`, resultando un orden de complejidad **cuadrático** respecto al número de dígitos del número binario.

Lo más común es construir la lista al revés (encabezando los elementos con `:`), y darle la vuelta al final con `reverse` en una única pasada. El operador `:` es el constructor de listas, que toma un elemento `x` y una lista `xs` y devuelve (en tiempo constante) la lista `x:xs` con cabeza `x` y cola `xs`. La función `reverse` invierte una lista en tiempo lineal, por lo tanto la función resultante tiene un orden de complejidad **lineal** respecto al número de dígitos del número binario:

```
toBin, auxBin :: Int -> [Int]
toBin 0 = [0]
toBin n = reverse (auxBin n)

auxBin 0 = []
auxBin n = n `mod` 2 : auxBin (n `div` 2)
```

## Número de unos

Para contar el número de `1` de la lista resultante, puedes filtrar los elementos iguales a `1` con la función `filter`, y luego calcular la longitud con la función `length`:

```
ghci> filter (==1) [1,0,0,1,1]
[1,1,1]
ghci> length (filter (==1) [1,0,0,1,1])
3
```

Combinándolo con `toBin` en una función:

```
countOnes :: Int -> Int
countOnes = length . (filter (==1)) . toBin
```

Otra opción más simple, utilizando simplemente ajuste de patrones:

```
numeroUnos :: [Int] -> Int
numeroUnos [] = 0
numeroUnos (1:xs) = 1 + numeroUnos xs
numeroUnos (_:xs) = numeroUnos xs
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Pero, sigue siendo poco eficiente para el ejercicio que me proponen que es calcular el numero de unos (en binario) de 2^100000000.

Answer (score 1):

Para calcular el número de unos, *population count*, no es necesario convertir el número a binario; puedes, por ejemplo, hacer uso del hecho de que ***x & (x - 1)*** tiene un uno menos que ***x***,

```
import Data.Bits

population_do 0 p = p
population_do x p = population_do ((.&.) x (x - 1)) (p + 1)
population x = population_do x 0
```

Comment: Me funciona muy bien, pero no la entiendo

Comment: Gracias, pero para el caso que me ponen no es eficiente   `numeroUnos (1+10^20000000)`